# Uncaught TypeError ao usar o Jquery Mask Plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Recebi o erro de "Uncaught TypeError" ao usar a função "mask" do jQuery 
Mask Plugin.

[image: erro no chrome]

Aqui estão meus includes no arquivo `editar_usuario.php`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $site."js/chama_ajax.js" ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $site."js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $site."js/jquery_mask_plugin/jquery.mask.min.js" ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $site."js/validacoes.js" ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $site."js/mascaras_edit.js" ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $site."js/js.js" ?>"></script>
```

Meu código das masks está no arquivo `mascaras_edit.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#cep_edit').mask('00000-000');
  $('#telefone_edit').mask('(00) 0000-0000');
  $('#celular_edit').mask('(00) 00000-0000');
  $('#cnpj_edit').mask('00.000.000/0000-00', {reverse: true});
  $('#cpf_edit').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
});
```

Aqui está o código (php/html) do form onde o a função mask está sendo utilizada.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group" id="cpf_div">
  <label>CPF</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cpf_edit" id="cpf_edit" size="40" value="<?php echo $r['cpf'];?>">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
  <label>Telefone Fixo</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="telefone_edit" id="telefone_edit" size="40" value="<?php echo $r['telefone'];?>">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
  <label>Telefone Celular</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="celular_edit" id="celular_edit" size="40" value="<?php echo $r['celular'];?>">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group" id="cep_div">
  <label>CEP</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="cep_edit" id="cep_edit" type="text" maxlength="9" size="40">
</div>
```

Tentei seguir dicas de outras perguntas feitas porém nada deu certo. Eu estou conseguindo usar o plugin em outras partes do código menos no form de edição, também tentei usar a função "masked" do plugin e não funcionou (nesse arquivo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confira se a ordem das bibliotecas se está correta. O carregamento do jQuery geralmente deve sempre vir antes. Veja abaixo o Mask Input funcionando. Verifique se os outros arquivos `.js` não estão causando algum conflito (veja se no console acusa algum erro).

Verifique também se esta variável `$site` está retornando o caminho correto das bibliotecas (veja no código-fonte).

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#cep_edit').mask('00000-000');
  $('#telefone_edit').mask('(00) 0000-0000');
  $('#celular_edit').mask('(00) 00000-0000');
  $('#cnpj_edit').mask('00.000.000/0000-00', {reverse: true});
  $('#cpf_edit').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.12/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group" id="cpf_div">
  <label>CPF</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cpf_edit" id="cpf_edit" size="40" value="<?php echo $r['cpf'];?>">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
  <label>Telefone Fixo</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="telefone_edit" id="telefone_edit" size="40" value="<?php echo $r['telefone'];?>">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
  <label>Telefone Celular</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="celular_edit" id="celular_edit" size="40" value="<?php echo $r['celular'];?>">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 form-group" id="cep_div">
  <label>CEP</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="cep_edit" id="cep_edit" type="text" maxlength="9" size="40">
</div>
```

Comment: Aparentemente era conflito com o outro arquivo de mascaras.